# How to link html page in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, dreamhost

I am new to html and wordpress world. i literally know nothing. Today i have to work on wordpress. My requirement is to create a basic subscription form in wordpress using which my users can subscriber to Dreamhost announcement list. I am able to create custom html formin wordpress which is working fine. If user filled in the details and click on submit button, a default message is displayed by dreamhost which i want to change and display my own page. The process to do that is given by dreamhost in their website, [please click here to go to website](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215683657-Custom-form-to-subscribe-unsubscribe-to-an-Announcement-List). The problem is i created custom page and linked the page and wordpress is returning 404 error. please help in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Word press has permalinks like ugly permalinks and  pretty permalinks. pretty permalinks wont work while integrating dreamhost with workpress as dreamhost will pass additional parameters to the URL which permalinks wont accept. Hence use ugly permalinks. Dream host announcement list custom form guidelines describes my explanation even more better.